# Сумма наибольших элементов строк матрицы

Tags: java

Дана матрица 4x4. Нужно найти сумму наибольших элементов строк матрицы.
Алгоритм создал, но, бывает, выдает отрицательные числа. Я думаю, проблема в том, что когда элементы строки матрицы, следующие за первым и больше первого, повторяются, алгоритм не срабатывает.

> 35 30 35 20
>
> 15 15 **25 25**
>
> 35 30 20 15
>
> 20 15 35 20

Помогите решить это.
Алгоритм в коде помечен комментарием.

Код:

```
class Lab2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         byte a = 5;
         byte sum = 0, max;
         byte B[][] = new byte[4][4];
         byte C[][] = new byte[4][4];

         for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
         {
             for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
             {
                 B[i][j] = (byte) (3 + (int) (Math.random() * 5));
             } 
         }

         System.out.println("Matrix B:");

         for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
         {
             for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
             {
                 System.out.print(B[i][j] + " ");
             }
             System.out.println();
         }

         for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
         {
             for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
             {
                 C[i][j] = (byte) (B[i][j] * a);
             } 
         }

         System.out.println("Matrix C:");

         for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
         {
             for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
             {
                 System.out.print(C[i][j] + " ");
             }
             System.out.println();
         }
         //counting the sum of the greatest elements of each row

         for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)  // ПРОБЛЕМА ЗДЕСЬ
         {
             max = C[i][0];
             for(int j = 1; j < 4; j++)
             {
                 if(C[i][j] > max)
                 {
                     max = C[i][j];
                 }
             }
             sum += max;
         }
         System.out.println("The sum of the greatest elements of each row is: " + sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы используете для всех целочисленных переменных тип `byte`, который в `Java` имеет диапазон от -128 до 127. Если при прибавлении к такой переменной получается число больше 127, происходит т.н. [переполнение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) и результирующее значение будет, можно сказать, циклически сдвинуто по этому диапазону. Результат будет не тот, который ожидался.

Если в матрице `B` у вас относительно небольшие числа, то в матрице `A` они могут достигать 35. То есть тип самой матрицы выбран верно. Но сумма максимальных элементов строк уже может достигать `35*4 = 140`, что при переполнении даст

```
-128 + (140 - 128) = -116  // вычитаем переполнение
```

Соответственно, для переменной `sum` нужно использовать более "широкий" тип, например, `short`.